# Execute IN() SQL query with JDBCTemplate

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I get error running the following query. I know that I need to use '?' as many as list size, but the size of list differs and I don't know how to replace the '?'.

```
public List<Object> findAllGrades(String pnr, List<String>codes) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select CourseParticipantship.grade from [thd].[dbo].[CourseParticipantship] "
                    + "inner join thd.dbo.CourseMaterial on courseMaterial_id = CourseMaterial.id "
                    + "inner join thd.dbo.Course on course_id = Course.id and Course.code in (?)"
                    + "inner join thd.dbo.Student on student_id = Student.id "
                    + "where Student.personalNumber in (?)",new Object[] { codes, pnr }, new RowMapper() {
                public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
                    return rs.getObject("grade");
                }
            });
}
```

I get this error: `Unable to convert between java.util.ArrayList and JAVA_OBJECT`

Comment: You should use `in` here: `+ "where S.pnr in (?)"`

Answer (score 2):

You should use in here: `+ "where S.pnr in (?)"`

You have to change

`+ "where S.pnr= ?",new Object[] { codes, pnr }, new RowMapper() {`

to

```
 + "where S.pnr in (?)",new Object[] { codes, pnr }, new RowMapper() {
```

Comment: doesn't work. Also 'pnr' is not a list, but 'code' is. I used 'in' in `C.code in ?` . The query is supposed to find grades of all codes for each pnr.

Comment: @nana Can you please add the whole stacktrace please?

Comment: I add it in the question

Comment: I think the problem is with my list. Because each element of the list has more than one 'code' in it. So it's not a list of codes, but it's a list of list of codes! any idea how to fix the query then?